# udp server respond on the basis of the request received from the udp client

Tags: c#

I am making a UDP application in which I am able to receive the messages from udp client and sending a result back to the udp client...but now i want to set the udp server responses on the basis of the request...like for example if udp client send "Hello" message to the server then server reacts accordingly that if the client send "world" then server reacts accordingly that....In short my problem is that i am not able to read out the string which i am receiving at the server site.....this is window form application in c#

for example here is the code:

```
        int recv;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];


        IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 1235);

        Socket newsocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        newsocket.Bind(endpoint);

        MessageBox.Show("waiting for a client..");

        IPEndPoint sen = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001);
        EndPoint tmp = (EndPoint)sen;

        recv = newsocket.ReceiveFrom(data, ref tmp);

        MessageBox.Show(" message recieved", tmp.ToString());

        MessageBox.Show(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv));
```

now i want to read out the string which i am receiving at the "recv" integer by which i could able to set the responses accordingly that..Please tell me How can i do that...

Comment: What shows up on the last messagebox?? it is suposed to show the string in the messagebox...

Answer (score 0):

see this 
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receive%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) maybe it can help, your code seams to be rigth, but if it is not working try to change the encoding

to compare the data to string you need first convert it to an string with this line of code

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv)
```

use like this

```
 recv = newsocket.ReceiveFrom(data, ref tmp);
        string receiver = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
            if (receiver == "Hello"){"do something"}
```

Comment: it's done, but i think he's code is rigth that line should return the string, and he is not reporting any erro about that...

Comment: Thank you very much guys my code is running there is no problem in the code but i want to set the condition to check the string at the "recv" variable for example....  if(recv=="hello") then { do something  } else if(recv == "world") then{ do something }

Comment: and this part is not running i need the responses of the server depending upon the message which i received from the client...

Comment: you can't compare an int with an string like that, first you need to convert the data to string